# Angularjs Typescript define directive with constructor parameters throws [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to use typescript to create an AngularJS 1.5 app and struggling to get the directive working which has an constructor parameter.

my Directive is something like this:

```
export class chModalDialog implements ng.IDirective {
        public restrict = 'A';

       //static $inject = ["$rootScope", "modalService"]
        constructor(
            private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
            private modalService: CH.Interfaces.IModalsService) {
        }


       public link(scope: any, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: any) {
            var self = this;
            scope.subview = null;
            element.on("click", function handleClickEvent(event) {
                if (element[0] !== event.target) {
                    return;
                }
                scope.$apply(self.modalService.reject);
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

I have a factory function defined like this:

```
function chModalDialogFactory($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, modalService: CH.Interfaces.IModalsService): ng.IDirective {
    return new CH.Directives.chModalDialog($rootScope, modalService);
}
chModalDialogFactory.$inject = ["$rootScope", "modalService"] //including $inject annotations
```

finally registering the directive as below:

```
angular.module('ch.controllers')
.directive('chModalDialog', chModalDialogFactory)
```

now when I try to make use of this directive I get the following error from Angular, can some please help me understand what I missed here?

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:9000/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
```